# SAS Dataframe to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sas

I am relatively new to Pandas and exploring stuffs. I have a requirement that explains as below. I am using AWS Console (SageMaker)

A group of SAS7BDAT files in a folder and each of these files are with different structure. These files are to be converted to CSV but has the following challenges.

1. All SAS7BDAT files has poor data quality. Say, column values has special characters within the data like '\r\nSkinProduct,Cream'(in this data the comma is allowed but not newline or carriage return)
2. When tried with sas7bdat_converter package with batch_to_csv    function, the    csv files creates with double quotes, numerical values are with float (say 200 value became 200.0)

I tried the below code but cant figure out what am I missing

```
from sas7bdat import SAS7BDAT 
file = "<folder/name/aaaa.sas7bdat"
with SAS7BDAT(file, skip_header=False) as reader:
    df = reader.to_data_frame()
df

import re
df1=df.apply(lambda k:re.sub("[\n\r\t]", "",df), axis=0, raw=False, result_type=None, args=())
df1
```

Can someone assist me please? (I haven't tried to convert to csv yet but would like to view the dataframe post quality corrections)

Comment: Can you add a snippet of how your df currently looks and what the expected df is like

Comment: Is this a one time process or something you need to script and automate? If it's one time, the SAS Universal Viewer (free) will convert the files to CSV for you which will be formatted correctly.

Comment: FYI - I don't think this statement is correct. 'All SAS7BDAT files have a poor quality'. SAS is more similar to a DB so their is specific types and formats available and it's unlikely to be poor quality. Most likely something is going wrong with your conversion process.

Comment: Sure. When I said poor data quality, I meant in my data files. Thank you for the responses. I have pasted the sample dataset thats from converted csv file. Its got the double quotes and because of the \n character present right inside the sasdata, the data went in as a new record. All are treated as string as well (but this I think I can handle post conversion as well).
Also, I need to script and automate within AWS Management Console.

Comment: @BhavaniRavi Below are the dataset

`"Product Key","Distribution Center","DATE_CHAR","Discount Indicator","Revenue in (1000s)"
"Alex's Anti Dandruff Shampoo 17 dl",
"Atlanta","02/10/2013","0","35966"
"Alex's Anti Dandruff Shampoo 17 dl","Atlanta","02/17/2013","0","25270"
"Alex's Anti Dandruff Shampoo 17 dl","Atlanta","02/24/2013","0","20980"
"Alex's Anti Dandruff Shampoo 17 dl","Atlanta","03/10/2013","0","21888"
"Alex's Anti 
Dandruff Shampoo 17 dl","Atlanta","03/17/2013","0","21517"
"Alex's Anti Dandruff Shampoo 17 dl","Atlanta","03/24/2013","0","20626"`

Answer (score 0):

##### Importing SAS Datasets

When important SAS files into Python, try using Pandas `.read_sas()` function. If characters are giving you trouble, trying passing `encoding='latin-1'` to the function.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_sas(file, encoding='latin-1')

df.head()
```

If the regular expression step is still necessary, can you provide an example of the current state of the text and what you want it to look like?

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes. Reading through sas works for me :D